# Query returning Union of two tables

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7

I'm trying to retrieve data from a table using multi-column subquery but it unions the result from both tables. I'm unable to modify it to get actual results.
Here is my query

```
select id from  Recipe,user_plan where Recipe.id in (select meal_number from user_plan where week_id=(select max(week_id) from user_plan where user_id=:user_id))
```

**Recipe Structure**

[image]

---

**user_plan structure**
[image]
It should return 2 rows as per my expectations and data available in tables but it is returning 10 rows.Please help me figure this out. Thanks.
I'm using mysql-server on ubuntu
**Sample Data for user_plan**

```
+---------+---------+-------------+-----------+
| user_id | week_id | meal_number | recipe_id |
+---------+---------+-------------+-----------+
|       1 |       1 |           1 |         1 |
|       1 |       1 |           3 |         1 |
|       2 |       2 |           2 |         2 |
|       2 |       4 |           2 |         2 |
|       3 |       3 |           3 |         3 |
+---------+---------+-------------+-----------+
```

**Expected Output**

```
+----+
| id |
+----+
|  1 |
|  3 |
+----+
```

**Actual Output**

```
+----+
 | id |
 +----+
 |  1 |
 |  3 |
 |  1 |
 |  3 |
 |  1 |
 |  3 |
 |  1 |
 |  3 |
 |  1 |
 |  3 |
 +----+
```

Comment: Can you post your fiddle and sample data?

Comment: post  a proper data sample and the expected  result (no image)  as tabular text

Comment: Also, what do you want?

Comment: updated the question

Comment: It looks to me like you are asking for a cartesian product of these two tables. Instead maybe `select * from Recipe INNER JOIN 
 user_plan ON Recipe.recipe_id = user_plan.recipe_id AND user_plan.week_id=(select max(week_id) from user_plan where user_id=:user_id) and user_plan.user_id = :user_id;`?

Comment: @JNevill it solved the issue. Thanks.. can you please add explanation  to your answer and what was wrong with my query. 
Also how can I avoid Cartesian product in my query. Thanks

Comment: @RaoWaqasAkram I've added an answer clarifying why this approach works and where your approach went off the rails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing:

```
FROM Recipe, user_plan
```

This is a very old style of joining tables, and it would be necessary to supply the relationship as a condition in the `WHERE` clause like

```
WHERE recipe.recipe_id = user_plan.recipe_id
```

Failing to do so will result in EVERY record from `Recipe` being joined to EVERY record from `user_plan` which is almost always undesirable.

You are always better off stating which type of join you are using in your `FROM` clause. Here an `INNER JOIN` would be appropriate. You then supply the relationship of the table in the `ON` clause following the `INNER JOIN`:

```
FROM Recipe INNER JOIN user_plan ON Recipe.recipe_id = user_plan.recipe_id
```

Now it's clear what tables are being joined and, more importantly, how they are being joined. From there the rest of your conditions can hang out in the WHERE clause:

```
 SELECT * 
 FROM Recipe INNER JOIN user_plan ON Recipe.recipe_id = user_plan.recipe_id 
 WHERE user_plan.week_id=(select max(week_id) from user_plan where user_id=:user_id) 
     and user_plan.user_id = :user_id;
```

Comment: Thanks for the explaination.